# Ошибка при записи в базу данных

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть такой код:

```
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `'$buildid'` (token) VALUES (?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $token);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Если вместо `'$buildid'` напишу название базы, то запрос уйдет. 
$buildid приходит корректный, запрос вроде бы тоже корректен, пробовал разные вариации с кавычками, всегда одно и то же.

Comment: POST запрос отправляю правильный, проверял.

Comment: С базой коннект тоже имеется.

Comment: `'$buildid'` вот этих ' ' не надо

Comment: какой результат будет если сделать `echo "INSERT INTO \`'$buildid'\` (token) VALUES (?)"` ?

Comment: *Откуда* приходит $buildid? И зачем вообще он должен приходить и почему нельзя написать имя таблицы прямо в запросе?

Comment: Всем спасибо. Решил вот так. '$buildid' вот этих ' ' не надо – Kirill Korushkin 15 часов назад

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если есть проблемы с вставкой переменной - попробуйте использовать конкатенацию:

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `" . $buildid . "` (token) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $token);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: можно ещё парсингом сделать "INSERT INTO {$buildid} (token) VALUES (?)"

Comment: протсо я не видел этот коммент

Answer (score 0):

```
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO {$buildid} (token) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $token);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Это же просто копия кода из вопроса. В чем состоит ваш ответ?

Comment: {$buildid} вот так надо писать там varibale

Comment: вот этого я написал